# How to throw exception from EVENT_DISPATCH event in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, listener

I would like to throw an exception from within the `EVENT_DISPATCH` event that gets handled identical to how it would have been handled had it been thrown from a controllers dispatch method. However I have no clue how to do so.

In the first piece of code the exception is not caught and no EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR is triggered. I tried to play with the `MvcEvent::setError` method but no clue there.

```
$this->listeners[] = $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onDispatch'), 100);


public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    if ($condition) {
        throw SomeException;
    }
}
```

versus

```
class Controller extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        if ($condition) {
            throw SomeException;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Roel, did you find the way to catch these exceptions? I'm also struggling with exception being thrown inside dispatch event.

Comment: I did not. It can't be done. See the posts below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that what you are trying to do is 100% possible.  You can get close, however.

The issue arises from the fact that ZF2 handles controller exceptions as an event, and the event manager determines what to do with those exceptions.  As you are throwing an exception from the event manager itself, it can't be handled in the same way as a controller exception.

One possible solution is to set a global exception handler in php:

```
public function onBootstrap( MvcEvent $e )
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach( MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array( $this, 'onDispatch' ) );

    //set the global exception handler
    set_exception_handler( array( $this, 'handleException' ) );
}

public function onDispatch( MvcEvent $e )
{
    if ( true )
    {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
}

public function handleException( \Exception $e )
{
    //do something with the exception
}
```

However, there are some drawbacks to taking this approach, as this will override the default handling of ALL exceptions in your application, so you may want to only allow it to handle specific exceptions and let the default handler support the rest, so:

```
public function handleException( \Exception $e )
{
    if ( $e instanceof MyExceptionClass )
    {
        //do something with the exception
    }
    else
    {
        //rethrow the exception
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

For more on this you can read the comments in the php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php#usernotes

Comment: Thanks for your explanation regarding why this cannot be done in ZF2. I'll grant you the points.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        if ($condition) {
            $e->getTarget()->getEventManager()->trigger('dispatch.error', $e);
        }
    }</strike>

ohhhh i am sorry , my bad ,'dispatch.error' can only be triggered before dispatch , i did it in onRoute event .

but if you want to throw exception in dispatch event try this , it worked for me:

**IMPORTANT**:the priority should be a negetive value for this to work

```
$em->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', array($this, 'onDispatch'), -100);

public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    throw new \Exception('This is Exception');
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. Nothing happends when I place this code inside of a dispatch listener. Furthermore, no exception is passed in any way.

Comment: This does not work in my case. The exception is thrown, but does not get caught by the framework and thus does not trigger the EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR event. Even with negative priority.

Answer (score 0):

in Module.php try something like that

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->attach( \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this,'onDispatch'), 100 );

}

public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    if ($condition) {
        throw SomeException;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously I registered the listener I mentioned in the module's Bootstrap method.